# Does QTP have any event handlers or test engine events?

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, testcomplete

I am currently working on a test automation project using QTP 10.0 and I am new to this.
I've worked with TestComplete automation tool where we had event handlers like OnStartTest, OnStopTest, OnLogError, OnLogWarning etc.,

I am planning on tweaking the current data driven framework to an automation object model and I wanted to know if we have such features so that I could bind my appropriate actions to those events.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**No. QTP does not have this kind of event handlers.** For flow control, you have the rather procedural test flow tree:

- Every test includes a test flow tree.
- The root of the test flow tree contains all actions that are executed in sequence when the test is executed. (The same holds true for action calls in those "root" actions; however, you never see the source for those calls, that´s why I mention it)
- The childnodes of the test flow shows which actions call which other action.
  There is way to define an event handler that is called before a certain action call returns, for example.